# Sidebar of HNQ shows only the users who asked the questions, but not those who answered it

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

The sidebar of the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/) shows the following:

> **Top Network Users**
>
> These users asked or provided top answers for the posts on this page
>
> [ List of users ]

The list of users only includes those users who asked the questions, but not a single user who answered it. This contradicts the text above the list of users.

Comment: The list is limited in number - doesn't mean that answerers never show up there. IIRC there is a bias towards askers.

Comment: @Oded Hmm. I've the highest scoring answer to HNQ [su] questions 7  times in the past few months and not appeared in the list. How big is the bias exactly?

Answer (score 4):

The section got renamed to Top Network Askers a while back.