# What purpose does the 'Top Network Askers' pane serve on the landing page?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com

In [Stack Exchange landing page](//stackexchange.com/), there is a "Top Network Askers" pane to the right:

> [image]

What purpose does it serve?

To clarify further, I'm not asking what it is (a list of users who asked the 'hot' questions) or how it is created (hotness points).

But the information on the 'Top Network Askers' pane is already available under each listed question: `asked X hours ago by <username> on Y`.

So what is the intent in presenting this information as a separate pane?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much use for it. The only thing it does is giving attention to those 'who make these sites awesome', just like the top askers and top answerers on the tag page.

Comment: Not the top answerers. It used to **say** top answerers but it never included them, so the words "top answerers" was removed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258499/sidebar-of-hnq-shows-only-the-users-who-asked-the-questions-but-not-those-who-a

Comment: I didn't say it were the answerers, I said it was just like the tag page, which includes the top askers and answerers @cat